# Controlling LED strip with Wemos D1 mini

Tags: transistors, esp8266, led-strip

I have a 12v led strip and have tested the current draw at ~500mA per colour.

I want to drive this via my Wemos GPIOs which are 3.3V @ 12mA max.

For testing I have been using 2N2222 transistors with 330Ω resistors and it seems to work well, in that the current draw is similar as via 12V directly. Ideally I should aim for 12mA base current right, so 220Ω resistor?

Although measuring the base current only gives 4mA which is less than I would have expected given (3.3 - 0.7)/330 = ~8mA, any explanation for this?

Also with a transistor gain of 500/8 = 62.5 (or 500/4 = 125?) I think the transistor is not fully switched on, and it does start to get hot quite quickly so this is probably true.

I suspect that gain is too high so I need to cascade 2 transistors to increase the gain in two steps. Like 5mA -> 50mA -> 500mA. So it would be something like GPIO 3.3V via 510Ω to give (3.3 - 0.7)/510 = 5mA, then 12V via 220Ω to give (12 - 0.7)/220 = 51mA

I also have some IRL540N mosfets which I tried but these don't fully switch on at 3.3v so would need a transistor to switch these anyway.

edit: Looking back at my original order for these transistors and these are what I bought https://www.aliexpress.com/item/2N2222A-Free-shipping-100pcs-in-line-triode-transistor-NPN-switching-transistors-TO-92-0-6A-30V/32816748799.html they say 2N2222A on the packaging but are not the old style metal case ones, so not entirely sure what they are now MSP2222 maybe?

[This is what I had in mind for the circuit](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%200.23988752939670982%2046%205%2049%0At%20368%20288%20400%20288%200%201%20-11.999999999849635%20-0.12216631841175775%20100%0Ar%20448%20112%20448%20224%200%2024%0Aw%20448%20320%20448%20384%201%0At%20400%20304%20448%20304%200%201%20-11.877833681202372%200.12216631852487103%20100%0Aw%20400%20272%20400%20224%200%0Aw%20448%20224%20448%20288%200%0AR%20304%20112%20240%20112%200%200%2040%2012%200%200%200.5%0Ag%20448%20384%20448%20400%200%0AR%20288%20288%20240%20288%204%205%201000%203.3%200%200%200.75%0Ar%20288%20288%20368%20288%200%201000%0Ar%20400%20224%20400%20112%200%20330%0Aw%20304%20112%20400%20112%200%0Aw%20400%20112%20448%20112%200%0Ao%201%204%200%204099%2020%200.8%200%202%201%203%0A)

Comment: At half voltage and half current --- 6v and 0.25 amp---- any 2N2222 wiii burn up. Unless you use duty cycle to modulate the average intensity.

Comment: What do you mean by half voltage, half current, half of what?

Comment: For a switch (or linear element, such as bipolar wires as linear amplifier) in series with a resistive load (we'll assume the LEDs behave like this), the **maximum** power dissipation is at half power and half voltage.

Comment: I don't understand where you got 6V & 0.25A from though, half of what exactly?

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend using a mosfet rather than a transistor to drive LED lights from a microcontroller such as a Wemos D1. The transistors I've tried get hot when conducting that level of power. Use a RFP30N06LE (available from Amazon for less than $1) instead for much better results as it can handle 30A@60V. Please see my [blog post](https://wordpress.com/post/geekout42.wordpress.com/131) on this subject for further details.